# How to check frequently to a artifactory repo and if we found any new artifacts that should start bamboo plan

Tags: devops, artifactory, build-automation, bamboo, artifacts

I have a Jenkins job outside my workplace network that creates artifacts and these are copied to my company artifactory. from there will run bamboo plan to deploy.
1)how can I search for new artifacts in artifactory to automatically start bamboo plan
2) how can we automate this process

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer here is a [User-Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) ([examples](https://github.com/JFrog/artifactory-user-plugins)).
You should probably write a user-plugin that will listen to an [afterCreate](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Storage) event and then trigger a REST call to the Bamboo server to trigger the build (probably via the [Build Queue Service](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/bamboo-rest-resources/#build-queue-service))

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can specifically use the Webhook plugin for this - https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/webhook